# Intel HD graphics 4400 not working properly on Wheezy

Tags: debian, gnome3, debian-wheezy, intel-graphics

Upon login, I get the following message:

> GNOME 3 Failed to Load
>
> Unfortunately GNOME 3 failed to start properly and started in the *fallback mode*.
>
> This most likely means your system (graphics hardware or driver) is not capable of delivering the full GNOME 3 experience.

Here's some more information:

```
$ grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[     2.866] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Invalid argument
```

(the error message actually shows some tens of times).

```
$ sudo lspci -vk|grep -A 10 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 041e (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
        Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: i915

$ uname -a
Linux orestis 3.10-0.bpo.3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.10.11-1~bpo70+1 (2013-09-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I seem to have all required packages installed (`xserver-xorg-video-intel` and `i965-va-driver`).

Comment: Does it start with startx?

Comment: No, with startx I have exactly the same symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get -d install --reinstall gdm
 sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
 sudo apt-get install gdm
```

(now you may be asked to choose your wm, I do not remember exactly, if so choose gdm)

```
 sudo reboot
```

Comment: I did the above, using `gdm3` instead of `gdm`, and also, for the fourth command, I told it `sudo apt-get install task-gnome-desktop` instead, which installed `gdm3` (and `gnome` and `gnome-core`, which had been uninstalled together with `gdm3`). No luck. (This is a fresh clean install of Wheezy, so I didn't think this could work.)

Comment: @AntonisChristofides Try lightdm?

Comment: Since I have the same symptoms with startx, isn't it unlikely that the problem is the display manager?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides yes, but unlikely, not certain, is the key word. It takes 30 seconds to try. The alternative is to re-install, google around and you'll see no other way around this error.

Comment: Tried it. Same symptoms, same messages in log.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously which Display Manager you use has zero to do with this issue.

Try a 3.12 kernel and if that does not work do the following:

1. First try a kernel built from intel hd 4400 linux http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~danvet/drm-intel/?h=drm-intel-next
2. If the solution above fails, bring it up on the developer list intel-gfx at freedesktop

Comment: 3.12 didn't work. I will wait for 3.13.

Comment: 3.13 doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with wheezy and i3-4130 CPU. I switched to testing and gnome 3 started to work out of the box, without any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install a bunch of packages from backports:

```
sudo apt-get install -t wheezy-backports linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 firmware-linux i965-va-driver xserver-xorg-video-intel
sudo service gdm3 restart
```

I also rebooted a few times and i'm not sure if *all* the above are necessary.